# How can i revert an action with Jquery and Sweet alerts?

Tags: jquery

I have the following code:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("#settings").submit(function (event) {

    event.preventDefault()
    Swal.fire({
      title: 'Confirm your order.',
      text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
      icon: 'warning',
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
      cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
      cancelButtonText: 'Go back',

      confirmButtonText: 'Yes'
    }).then((result) => {

       callAJAX(viewsurl,
       {"X-CSRFToken": getCookie("csrftoken") },
       parameters={'amount': $('#amount').val()},

      'post',
       function(data){
        console.log('success')
    })

  });
});
</script>
```

This is a [SweetAlerts](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#examples) panel, it will show a simple confirm message where, if the button `Yes` is hit, it will fire a POST request. Until now, it works; the problem is that if i hit the  `Cancel` button the POST request is sent, while nothing should happen. How can i fix this? Any advice is appreciated

Comment: See https://sweetalert2.github.io/#handling-dismissals

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `.then` block you need to check the value for the button

```
then((result) => {

    if(result.value == “Yes”){
       //to do....
    }
 })
```